# Dividing by Monomials Paradox

Tags: algebra-precalculus

is $8x^2 \div 4x$ the same as $\frac{8x^2}{4x}$, which equals 2x, or we must use the order of operations such that $\frac{8x^2}{4} \times x$ which equals $2x^3$

Comment: @MHONOR -- What book is it from? Also, does the author provide any worked examples?

Comment: you are a different type of evil

Comment: it was from an exam for the 2nd semester for 8th grade 
the students studied Dividing by Monomials in the 1st semester which considered the first result 
and studied the order of operations in the 2nd semester  which considered the second result 
but what is the right answer
i'd like to think that in Dividing by Monomials the divisor considered between Parentheses even if it is not written

Answer (score 3):

The spacing strongly supports the first interpretation (else it would be a deliberately misleading trick question).

However, assuming the first interpretation was intended, the standard way to write the expression would be
$$\frac{8x^2}{4x}$$ 
which avoids misinterpretation since the fraction bar qualifies as a grouping symbol.

But if you wanted the latter interpretation, then, in order *not* to be misleading, each operation should be shown explicitly, as in
$$8 \times x^2 \div 4 \times x$$

or better, grouped, as in

$$\left(\left(8 \times x^2\right)\div 4\right) \times x$$

Finally, context should be considered. If the problem is from a chapter on order of operations, then I would choose the latter interpretation (i.e., strict order of operations). If it's from a chapter discussing adding, subtracting, multiplying, and dividing monomials, then, most likely, the former interpretation was intended (even though the author should have expressed it in fraction form).

Also, as I suggested in one of my comments, assuming the problem is from a book, see if the author provides any worked examples with expressions of the given form.